# Listing all records j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui, rms

I want to list all records in the record store. I've declared a list:

```
Private List tlist = new List("Select One", List.IMPLICIT);
```

Also enumerated the records:

```
Form mainf;
Command exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
RecordEnumeration re = null;
int numrecords = 0;
    try {
        re = contactList.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
        numrecords = re.numRecords();
    } catch (RecordStoreException rse ) { numrecords = 0;}
```

Now I just need to know how to  list all the records in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `Record` into `Vector` and use the loop for append the `Vector` values into `List`. See below sample code,

```
RecordStore s =  RecordStore.openRecordStore(recordStoreName, true);
RecordEnumeration e = s.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
Vector vector = new Vector();
while(e.hasNextElement()) {
  vector.addElement(new String(e.nextRecord()));
}
List l = new List(null, CENTER);
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
  l.append(vector.elementAt(i).toString(), null); 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean 'while(e.hasNextElement())' ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code,

```
public String [] getRecordData()
{
    String[] str = null;
    int counter = 0;
    try 
    {
        RecordEnumeration enumeration = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
        str = new String[rs.getNumRecords()];

        while(enumeration.hasNextElement())
        {
            try 
            {
                str[counter] = (new String(enumeration.nextRecord()));
                counter ++;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```